# Regular Expression String Break

Tags: php, regex, string

I am fairly new to regex. I have been trying to break string to get the initial part of the string to create folders.

Here are few examples of the variables that I need to break.

`test1-792X612.jpg`

`test-with-multiple-hyphens-612X792.jpg`

Is there a way using regular expression that I can get `test1` and `test-with-multiple-hyphens`?

Comment: Do you need regex? Maybe use `substr("test1-792X612.jpg", 0, -12)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
(.*?)-\d+x\d+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iQ7yJ5/1)**

[image]

The idea is that the pattern will match the string with the `-NumXNum` but capture the previous content. Note the case insensitive flag.

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-5]   `test1`
MATCH 2
1.  [18-44] `test-with-multiple-hyphens`
```

If you don't want to use the insensitive flag, you could change the regex to:

```
(.*?)-\d+[Xx]\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain that all filenames end with 000X000 (where the 0's are any number), this should work:

```
/^(.*)-[0-9]{3}X[0-9]{3}\.jpg$/
```

The value from `(.*)` will contain the part that you're looking for.

In case there could be more or fewer numbers, but at least one:

```
/^(.*)-[0-9]+X[0-9]+$\.jpg/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple regex:

```
(.+)(?=-.+$)
```

***Explanations***:

**(.+)** : *Capture desired part*

**(?=-.+$)** : *(Positive Lookahead) Which is following a dashed part*

[**Live demo**](http://regex101.com/r/hA0yV6/3)

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to break the hyphenated parts of a file into directories. The expression [`(.*?)-([^-]+\.jpg)$`](http://regex101.com/r/oV7eB7/1) will capture everything before and after the last `-` in a `.jpg` file. You can then use [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to match/capture these groups and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split the `-` into different directories.

```
$files = array(
    'test1-792X612.jpg',
    'test-with-multiple-hyphens-612X792.jpg',
);

foreach($files as $file) {
    if(preg_match('/(.*?)-([^-]+\.jpg)$/', $file, $matches)) {
        $directories = explode('-', $matches[1]);
        $file = $matches[2];
    }
}

// 792X612.jpg
// Array
// (
//     [0] => test1
// )
//
// 612X792.jpg
// Array
// (
//     [0] => test
//     [1] => with
//     [2] => multiple
//     [3] => hyphens
// )
```

Comment: Can someone explain the -1? If it was OP, then I'm assuming I just misunderstood the question and can tweak it.

Comment: Okay, let me know if you have any questions. I focused on the PHP side of things, since it seemed like that is where you were getting confused. You may be able to integrate some of the other regular expressions if you like them more (they are a little more specific on the `###X###`).